# Input:checked + aside, is it possible to target other elements?

Tags: html, css

In my html right now I have the label and input above the aside which I am trying to toggle like so:

```
<label for="hamburger"><img src="images/hamburger.png"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="hamburger" />
<aside>
     <!-- stuff -->
</aside>
<main>
    <!-- stuff -->
</main>
```

To make things a little complicated, the hamburger only shows up once we reach a media query of max-width 768px like so:

```
@media(max-width:768px) {
aside {
    margin: -335px;
}
main {
    margin-left: 0;
}
label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#hamburger:checked + aside {
    margin: 0px;
}
}
```

So what happens is the aside gets pulled to the left, which makes it invisible, the main now fills the screen and its margin disappears and the label(#hamburger) shows up. When I click the newly appeared #hamburger it toggles back and forth between the aside showing up and not showing up. The problem I am having is this: I would like for the hamburger to move with the main section as I toggle back and forth, instead of sitting above the aside in the html. But if I move the label and checkbox inside the main I can't target the aside because #hamburger:checked + aside (for the + to work, I need to have it directly above it).

So the question is can I target other class with #hamburger:checked .class {}, because if I can, I cant seem to figure out how. If I cant do that how can I work around it?

I am sorry for the long winded question but I wanted to make sure I'm thorough in explaining my problem.

Comment: `#hamburger:checked + aside + main` works fine

Comment: Yeah but that assumes that I would have the same styles for both of them. I would like the freedom to style them.

Comment: No necessarily. You can style each selector as you wish.

Comment: Oh nvm, Im retarted. I see what you mean. I'll mess around with it and see what happens. Ty

Comment: It still doesnt give me the freedom to do what I'm looking for tho.